# How to keep data from router parameters on refresh in Angular?

Tags: angular

I wonder, in angular, how to keep data from router parameters on refresh? I tried this and it does not work on refresh, thanks.

Here is the constructor, it fetches the data correctly, but crashes on refresh.

```
    constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute ,
      ) {
        this.router.events.subscribe(
          (event: any) => {
            this.items = this.route.snapshot.data.myProducts;
            localStorage.setItem('s',JSON.stringify( this.items));
          }
        );
```

Comment: Please share the code for the the component i.e content of .html and .ts files, what errors are you getting in the console when you refresh?

Comment: Try to wrap your subscription inner code in `if (event instanceof NavigationStart)` see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried 'NavigationStart', it doesnt even fetch for when the page loads for the first time, thx tho

Comment: try using queryParams.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.router.events` in your code. `router` is not defined in the code you have shared. If you are looking to grab router parameters, you should subscribe to `params` from `ActivatedRoute`.

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
   this.items = params;
   localStorage.setItem('s', JSON.stringify(this.items));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the logic below worked for me,thanks

```
 constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute ,
      ) {
          if(this.route.snapshot.data){
        
            this.items = this.route.snapshot.data.myProducts;
            localStorage.setItem('it',JSON.stringify( this.items));
          
        }
          else {
           this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('it') || '[]');
         }
```